# Image of a complete space under an isometric embedding

Tags: isometry, complete-spaces

Suppose $(X, d_X)$ is a complete metric space and $f\colon X \to Y$ an isometric embedding into the metric space $(Y, d_Y)$.

Claim: $f(X)$ is closed in $Y$.

Proof:  Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of points in $X$ whose image $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to a $y \in Y$.
            Then, $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and since the embedding is isometric, so is $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, which therefore converges in the complete space $X$ to an $x \in X$.
            It follows that
            \begin{equation*}
    d_Y(y_n, f(x))
    = d_X (x_n, x) \to 0
   \end{equation*}
            and therefore $y = f(x) \in f(X)$.

All correct?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Γιωργη its ok man.